# Cufon text not appear IE8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, cufon

The url http://www.sydneybeeandwaspremoval.com.au
it works fine in **IE9** and Chrome, etc. But in **IE8** it doesn't work quite as expected, in **IE7** it also works properly.

But basically the top navigation menu is all a custom font using cufon, the first level links are working fine, however the second level links are replaced appropriately with cufon canvas and cufontext BUT you cant see it, I have inspected the elements to find the positions are correct, i have also tried removing all background images and changing color just in case, but this also did not help, its as if it has visibility hidden on them but I couldn't find any CSSthat could cause it.
Any ideas suggestions or experience will be much appreciated.

Comment: Is there any reason you're still using cufon? @font fact now works in all major browsers, and is much more reliable.

Comment: purchased template unfortunately, only included the js not the font files

Comment: Ah, that would be one good reason. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bug is discussed here: http://drupal.org/node/834636

The problem is, hidden elements with `visibility: hidden` are not properly rendered by Cufon in IE8. Then the solution is to replace the `visibility` property for the `display` property.

In your `templates/theme484/css/template.css` file, replace the line 431 by this one:

```
.menu-nav li ul { position: absolute; top: 44px; left: -14px; z-index: 100; width: 300px; display: none; }
```

And replace the line 433 with this:

```
.menu-nav li.parent:hover ul { display: block; }
```

Comment: Thankyou for this detailed answer, I was looking for a proper solution and cause such as this, so you have my thanks for it =]

Answer (score 0):

Kieran,

If everything is working in ie7, one solution could be to force ie8 to run your site in compatibility mode. In the < head > of page:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
```

Further more, you can target ie8 only to run in compatibility mode by doing this:

```
<!--[if IE 8]>
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
<![endif]-->
```

Good luck.